# geocoder near method throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

It works if **address** and **reverse_geocoded_by** are in the class which I don't need (latitude and longitude comes from rest client).

To find all locates within 5 miles

```
Locate.near([center.latitude, center.longitude], 5)
```

Schema

```
create_table :locate do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  # t.string :address
  t.float :latitude
  t.float :longitude

  t.timestamps
end
```

Model Class

```
class Locate < ApplicationRecord

  # reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
  # after_validation :reverse_geocode, unless: -> (obj) { obj.address.present? },
        #   if: -> (obj) { obj.latitude.present? and obj.latitude.present? and ( obj.latitude_changed? || obj.longitude_changed? ) }
end
```

Controller method

```
def near
  center = @user.locate
  render json: Locate.near([center.latitude, center.longitude], 5, units: :km)
end
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `near' for #Class:#):
```

Answer (score 1):

Geocoder does not add these scope methods to every model. It requires you to add either `geocoded_by` or `reverse_geocoded_by` to your model if you want it to gain the Geocoder methods and scopes like `.near`, `.geocoded`, etc...

Making a call to one of these two class macros is the hook that configures the geocoding options and `extends` your model with these methods. Again, Geocoder does *not* add these methods directly to ActiveRecord::Base and by extension every model in your application. Geocoder does *not* infer simply from the presence of `latitude:float longitude:float` in your schema that you want the model to be "geocodable". Geocoder does *not* go looking for these columns in any of your tables at all.

This is the bare minimum you'll have to do to get the functionality you're looking for

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
```

Think of it like this: If you add `post_id:integer` to your `Comment` model, do you automatically get a `#post` method? No, you have to explicitly add `belongs_to :post`. This is exactly the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder needs to know which columns store latitudes and longitudes, or how to get the location for the instance to do any calculation. So you need to set either `geocoded_by` or `reverse_geocoded_by`. (the reason is that without knowing either of these information, geocoder cannot know the location of your objects, so cannot calculate the distance between any objects and your supplied location).

Comment: Absolutely and then it gives me this error- NoMethodError (undefined method `near' for #Class:#):  when it does not use reverse geocoding -  #reverse_geocoded_by as it does not need.

Comment: Error comes when I don't use #reverse_geocoded_by or I comment it out

Comment: Right, so you do need `#reverse_geocoded_by` if you want to use coordinates in `Locate.near`. If you don't want to use `#reverse_geocoded_by` then you need to use an address rather than coordinates.

Comment: basically, do you mean #near(address, 5, units: :km) does need to have first parameter an address than [center.latitude, center.longitude]

Comment: sorry I just checked the source code and I was wrong. It doesn't need call reverse geocoding when you supply coordinates. Instead, you need to add `geocoded_by`

Comment: why? just explain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151006/discussion-between-ej2015-and-srs).

Comment: I have t.float :latitude and t.float :longitude in Locate model. #reverse_geocoded_by and geocoded_by is to map the latitude and longitude to street address and vice-versa. but since I am getting them from mobile gps, I want to save the limited geocoding calls to place apis (google, bing etc) instead call #near with [latitude, longitude] values